# Create new Jenkins jobs using Pipeline Job and Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins pipeline Job with parameters (name, group, taskNumber)

I need to write pipeline script which will call groovy script (this one?: https://github.com/peterjenkins1/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/add-job.groovy)

I want to create new job (with name name_group_taskNamber) every times when I build main Pipeline Job.

I don't understand:
Where do I need to put may groovy script ?
How does Pipeline script should look like? :

```
node{
    stage('Build'){
        def pipeline = load "CreateJob.groovy"
        pipeline.run()
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is to use the `jobDsl` step (from the [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and configure a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) like here (a git repo): https://github.com/lvthillo/shared-library . You need to configure this in your Jenkins global configuration.

It contains a folder `vars/`. Here you can manage pipelines and groovy scripts like my `slackNotifier.groovy`. The script is just a groovy script to print the build result in Slack.

In the jenkins pipeline job we will import our shared library:

```
@Library('name-of-shared-pipeline-library')_

mavenPipeline {
  //define parameters
}
```

In the case above also the pipeline is in the shared library but this isn't necessary.

You can just write your pipeline in the job itself and call only the function from the pipeline like this:
This is the script in the shared library:

```
// vars/sayHello.groovy
def call(String name = 'human') {
    echo "Hello, ${name}."
}
```

And in your pipeline:

```
final Lib= library('my-shared-library')

...
  stage('stage name'){
    echo "output"
    Lib.sayHello.groovy('Peter')
  }
...
```

**EDIT:**
In new declarative pipelines you can use:

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'xxx' } }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3', artifactNumToKeepStr: '1'))
    }

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "execute say hello script:"'
                sayHello("Peter")
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}

def sayHello(String name = 'human') {
    echo "Hello, ${name}."
}
```

output:

```
[test] Running shell script
+ echo 'execute say hello script:'
execute say hello script:
[Pipeline] echo
Hello, Peter.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Comment: I don't think that it's good idea.  When we have such kind of library it takes us to think about security more. Is it possible to add full script into pipeline without shared resources?

Comment: @Anna I've adapted the answer with a case where you can use a groovy function in your script immediately

Answer (score 0):

We do it by using the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jobcopy+Builder+plugin, try build another step in pipeline script and pass the parms which are to be considered

Comment: I needn't to have a copy. I just need three new clear jobs such as : test, preprod, prod. I want to configure pipeline-main-job-creator for this.

Comment: The above plugin will create new jobs based on a pre-configured template job, we have a common template and based on the needs we just change the parms / config to be replaced for each job type